# How do I fix this search method?

Tags: c

How do I fix this search method? This part is a switch statement that asks the user to search for a client ID.

```
case 2: printf("Enter the client ID to search for: ");
                    scanf("%d", searchID);
                    searchClient(searchID, pcli, clCount);
                    foundAt = searchClient(searchID, pcli, clCount);
                    if(foundAt >= 0)
                        printf("%d is found at position %d in the array", searchID, foundAt);
                    else
                        printf("%d is not found anywhere", searchID);
                break;
```

This is the search method itself that is called in case 2

```
int searchClient(char* searchID, client* pcli, int clCount)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < clCount; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(searchID,(pcli + i)->clID)==0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}//end searchClient
```

Comment: What is `searchID`? You *do* know that the arguments to `scanf` needs to be pointers, right?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It is, but a surprising one: `char * searchID`. Ouch.

Comment: searchID is supposed to be the input ID to search for in an array of ID's.

Comment: What error do you get? Show us your searchID definition.

Comment: @Takume: You're currently misusing pointers and/or `scanf`. Have you read an article or the IO chapter of a well-written C book yet?

Comment: I wish, so wish, there were a way to have reading [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as mandatory *before* posting on SO. Regardless, the docs on [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) are likely going to help, so reading them would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

the search function wants a string, but you're giving it an integer, 
perhps change the input dialogue like this:

```
printf("Enter the client ID to search for: ");
{
    char mybuffer[100];
    scanf("%99s", mybuffer);
    foundAt = searchClient(mybuffer, pcli, clCount);
}
```